# How to run a GUI without desktop in Raspberry PI

Tags: raspberry-pi

I want to run my GUI in Raspberry PI but i dont want Raspberry PI's desktop to seen and Nobody can acces the desktop or my codes. Is that possible? if it is how ?
by the way i coded my gui by Python and Pyqt.

Comment: maybe [boot2qt](http://qtandeverything.blogspot.com/2020/03/qt-on-raspberrypi.html) can help you?

Comment: actually it is not exactly what i am looking for